# Create map of histogram with relative frequency

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with a variable "x" and a "flag", like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import random

x_a = [np.random.normal() for y in range(10**4)]
x_b = [np.random.normal() for y in range(10**3)]
#x_c = [np.random.normal() for y in range(10**2)] # in this case density=True works fine
x_c = [random.choice([0, 1, 2]) for y in range(10**2)] # in this case density=True doesn't work

x = x_a + x_b + x_c

flag_a = ['a' for y in range(10**4)]
flag_b = ['b' for y in range(10**3)]
flag_c = ['c' for y in range(10**2)]
flag = flag_a + flag_b + flag_c

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'flag': flag})
df.head()

            x   flag
0    1.311679   a
1   -1.096678   a
2    0.118205   a
3    1.364317   a
4    0.542725   a
```

I would like to have the histogram plot of x for each flag, trying with

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='flag')
g.map(plt.hist, 'x', bins=20)
```

leads to

[image: map hist]

while I would like to have the relative frequency, in order to compare the distribution between flags with different count.

Please note that `density=True` doesn't help.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='flag')
g.map(plt.hist, 'x', bins=20, density=True)
```

gives

[image]

When bins are really "thin" they become very tall and the vertical axis greater than 1. I don't want it, as I expect the maximum to be 1 = 100%.

Comment: I still don't understand why `density=True` isn't what you want... Values >1 for the vertical axis are fine; this just reflects the units of your x-axis as the requirement is that Probability density (area under the curve) is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I couldn't understand why I was getting vertical axis values greater than 1. Still I don't want them as I expect the maximum frequency to be 1 or 100%.

Comment: Yes this is a bit unfortunate You used to be able to do this with `normed=True`, though that was deprecated in favor of `density=True`. I guess you could still do that, though you face a warning. I guess it's possible by manually plotting and adjusting the bar heights return from `np.hist`, though it wont be simple.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use `seaborn` for this then you need to set `sharey` as `False` when you create the `FacetGrid` ([link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)). So change

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='flag')
```

to

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='flag', sharey=False)
```

and you'll get

[image]

for the one with `np.random.normal()` or

[image]

for the one with `np.random.choice([0, 1, 2])`. Should work with `density=True` or `density=False`.

Alternative is create axis objects directly, if you need more fine tuned control over their creation and scaling, etc...

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12, 4))
flags = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for ax, flag in zip(axs, flags):
    h = max(np.histogram(df[df['flag'] == flag]['x'].values, bins=20)[0])
    ax.hist(df[df['flag'] == flag]['x'].values, bins=20)
    ax.set_ylim([0, h*1.1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about `sharey=False`. Still I'm working on it as I would like to show the frequency in percentage on y axis. Maybe I need to change y tick labels, showing on the first tick label total count like "1.000 = 100%" would be top.